# Docker Compose Solr authentication: No authentication configured

Tags: docker, docker-compose, solr

I am having issues adding auth to Solr in a Docker container. I have tried copying the `security.json` file to the Solr container's `$SOLR_HOME` folder. But it's returning a response at http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/authentication:

```json
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0},
  "errorMessages":["No authentication configured"]}
```

security.json:

```json
{
"authentication":{ 
   "blockUnknown": true, 
   "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
   "credentials":{"solr":"IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0= Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c="}, 
   "realm":"My Solr users", 
   "forwardCredentials": false 
},
"authorization":{
   "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
   "permissions":[{"name":"security-edit",
      "role":"admin"}], 
   "user-role":{"solr":"admin"} 
}}
```

I'm copying the file in the docker-compose.yml in the volume:

```
version: "3"
services:
  index:
    image: solr:8.11.1
    ports:
     - "8983:8983"
    volumes:
      - data:/var/solr
      - ./security/security.json:/opt/solr-8.11.1/server/solr/security.json
    command:
      - solr-precreate
      - archive_poc_core
volumes:
  data:
```

When I go into the container and check if the file is there with the settings, I can find it. So I don't think that's the problem. I think that the file is copied after solr is started but not sure how to get the security file prior on the container or what the correct way of doing it should be.

Any help, guidance or advice would be appreciated.

Guides I looked at:

- https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_1/basic-authentication-plugin.html#enable-basic-authentication
- https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/authentication-and-authorization-plugins.html#using-security-json-with-solr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working with help from a colleague of mine. We ended up using Zookeeper for managing the Apache side of things.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  solr1:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: solr.Dockerfile
    container_name: solr1
    ports:
     - "8983:8983"
    volumes:
      - data:/var/solr
    environment:
      - ZK_HOST=zoo1:2181
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
  zoo1:
    tty: true
    image: zookeeper:3.6.2
    container_name: zoo1
    restart: always
    hostname: zoo1
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888;2181
volumes:
  data:
```

solr.Dockerfile:

It copies over the files I needed like the `security.json` and `solr-security.sh`. It also adds in the entrypoint when building.

```
FROM solr:8.11.1

COPY security/security.json security.json
COPY scripts/solr-security.sh /usr/bin/solr-security.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/solr-security.sh"]
```

solr-security.sh:

This executes the authentication for Solr via Zookeeper, you can find out more here https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/authentication-and-authorization-plugins.html#in-solrcloud-mode

Then starts up the default entrypoint for Solr after the authentication has been done.

```
#!/bin/bash
solr zk cp /opt/solr-8.11.1/security.json zk:security.json -z zoo1:2181
exec /opt/docker-solr/scripts/docker-entrypoint.sh "$@"
```

Everything worked as expected when browsing to Solr, it showed the login screen. I hope this helps someone else who was trying to resolve this.